# Passing a const parameter by reference in vb.net

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [References in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389426/references-in-vb-net)

I want to pass a medium large Customer db object, but I don't want to pass it by value, because I think it would be unnecessary.

In c++ when you had a large object it was inefficient to pass it by value, because a copy was created from it, so you passed it by reference so that there was no copy (of the object passed) created. I used to pass the parameter as a constant because that way if I tried to change the object inside the function the compiler wouldn't let me so that I wouldn't harm the passed object (because it was passed by reference). Is it possible to mimick this in vb.net or is it not needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My strong suspicion is that you're getting confused about how values are passed in VB.

If your CustomerDb type is a *class*, then every expression of that type will have a value which is already a reference. By default, that reference will be passed by value - but it's still only the *reference* which is passed, not a whole object.

If your CustomerDb type is a *structure*, then you really will be passing the whole value each time - and you should strongly consider changing it to a class anyway...

Of course, when you pass a reference by value, that doesn't stop the object from being modified *within* the method, but it does mean that changes to the parameter variable itself aren't reflected in the calling code.

Read my article on [C# parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) - it's much the same in VB.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll vote to close this as a duplicate though.

Comment: I loved your in-depth explanation of parameter passing in "C# in depth" :)

Comment: While the parameter variable itself still points to the same object, changes to the internal state of that object within the method will be reflected in the calling code.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Indeed. That's what the third paragraph is meant to imply - the article goes into a lot more detail.

Comment: Just clarifying for the person asking - I knew you had this sorted out. (great article by the way).

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, classes (which I assume `Customer` is) are reference types. Passing a reference type as an argument will pass a reference (pointer) to the object. So passing a class is perfectly efficient and no copy is created.

If you pass a class by reference, then the method could change the reference (pointer) and it would be reflected in the calling method.

I don't know off the top of my head if there's an easy way to make the argument read only. Since reference types do pass a reference, any changes to the object will be reflected in the original. You might need a copy if you don't want the original to be modified.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll vote to close this as a duplicate though